# Syntax error "Statement is not accessible"

Tags: abap

I've got the following syntax error in line 22 of my program:

> Statement is not accessible.

Why and how to solve?

Code:

```
REPORT zabap01_sue02. 

START-OF-SELECTION. 

DO 3 TIMES. 
  PERFORM call_subr01. 
ENDDO . 

FORM call_subr01.
  DATA: lv_val TYPE I. 
  lv_val = lv_val + 1. 
  WRITE:/ 'local variable', lv_val. 
ENDFORM.

WRITE: /'1111111111111111111111111'. "<========= line 22

*INCLUDE zabap01_sue02_zll.
```

Comment: Next time please also add the error message in english to your question.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I have made your question compliant with stackoverflow rules. Please read the Tour & Help FAQs.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is; you can write any code after subrutine. Move your code which is on line 22 to before **FORM** directive.

Comment: but i do not understand Why can't subroutines be written in the middle?

Comment: May be it is not clear for reading code between subroutines. So ABAP not permit it. Keep code clean, split your report to includes, etc.

Comment: REPORT zabap01_sue02.


START-OF-SELECTION.

  DO 3 TIMES.
    PERFORM call_subr01.
  ENDDO .
    INCLUDE zabap01_sue02_zll.
  WRITE: /'1111111111111111111111111'.

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&  包含                ZABAP01_SUE02_ZLL
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM call_subr01.
  DATA: lv_val TYPE I.
  lv_val = lv_val + 1.
  WRITE:/ 'local variable', lv_val.
ENDFORM.   also wrong , i must write include begin or end

Comment: You not needed included for this sample. I try to give some perspective.

Answer (score -1):

To make it work, you put this part of the code into your main program: (the `INCLUDE X` should be put all the way at the bottom)

```
REPORT zabap01_sue02. 

START-OF-SELECTION. 

DO 3 TIMES. 
    PERFORM call_subr01. 
ENDDO. 

WRITE: /'1111111111111111111111111'. 

INCLUDE zabap01_sue02_zll.
```

And then create an Include, which contains your function.

```
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*    
* ZABAP01_SUE02_ZLL   
*---------------------------------------------------------------------* 
FORM call_subr01. 

DATA: lv_val TYPE I. 

lv_val = lv_val + 1. 
WRITE:/ 'local variable', lv_val. 

ENDFORM.
```

**Alternatively, don't use an Include at all** and just have this code in your program:

```
REPORT zabap01_sue02.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  DO 3 TIMES.
    PERFORM call_subr01.
  ENDDO.

  WRITE: /'1111111111111111111111111'.

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  call_subr01
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM call_subr01.

  DATA: lv_val TYPE i.

  lv_val = lv_val + 1.
  WRITE:/ 'local variable', lv_val.

ENDFORM.                    "call_subr01
```

The reason you can't write any code after a subroutine is because of the structure of the program. Since **FORMS can only be executed when called**, the first `FORM X` signals the program that there is nothing underneath it that needs to be executed anymore. So if there is code there, the compiler will show a syntax error.

It isn't a good idea to put subroutines in between code anyways, because that would be confusing and hard to read. As long as the names you give the FORMS are easy to understand, the code will be more readable. You can always go to the code of the subroutines quickly by clicking them.

Comment: so the form is called directly.whatever's in the middle,it's going to be skipped,right?

Comment: Yes, when a form is called, everything between the `PERFORM X` and the `FORM X` is skipped. Then when the code in the FORM is finished, it goes back to the line after the `PERFORM X`. You can look at how it works if you use the last code I gave you and go through it in the debugger step-by-step.

Comment: I have adjusted the question to make it "stackoverflow compliant". It didn't refer to INCLUDE except as a comment line. The question was more about the syntax error. I understand that my edit makes the first part of your answer out of context, and I'm sorry for that. Maybe it's better, if you don't mind, that you adjust it? (maybe just removing the first part about INCLUDE, I feel the rest keeps consistent).

Comment: If you look at the comment he wrote under the other answer, he un-commented the INCLUDE line. So I felt I should give him an example of the code working within an Include as well.

Comment: The OP proposed that code only because he was told a best practice is to split the code into several Include programs, but that advice was not related to the main question (approximately why is code not accepted outside FORMs).

Comment: No, the picture he posted in his question at the start showed his original code. He had already tried with the Include. The question got edited, so the picture is gone now, but his code had the Include from the start.

Comment: All right. We won't agree but I restored the original commented line so that the question and your answer keep coherent.